# Can exception handling of object whose constructor throw an exception be near its stack-based creation on code?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to make my C++ code exception-safe, and got a problem that neither asking friends nor searching web will help.

On my understanding, when creating an object with constructor potentially throw an exception, the code for creation needs to be enclosed with `try` block and exception handling is done in `catch(){}`.

If the creation is heap-based(e.g. `new`ed with default allocator), I can place exception handling code near the creation like this:

```
void f() {
  // work unrelated to Hoge object here

  try {
    Hoge *pHoge = new Hoge(); // could throw an exception
  } catch(HogeException& ex) {
    // handle exception
  }

  // rest of work here
}
```

However, if the creation is stack-based, I can't find ways to do that and resort to code like below due to the scope of `try` block:

```
void g() {
  // work unrelated to Hoge object here

  try {
    Hoge hoge; // could throw an exception

    // rest of work here
  } catch(HogeException& ex) {
    // handle exception
  }
}
```

If `// rest of work` code above is large, the distance of locations between object creation and exception handling could be long, decreasing code readability...

I prefer the exception handling code is near object creation(and maybe that is one of the concepts of `try`-`catch` structure). Is there any solutions?

Comment: `Hoge hoge();` could not throw an exception, as it is a function declaration (a vexing parse), not a variable declaration/initialization.

Comment: @jpalecek I mean to make an instance of type `Hoge` object named `hoge` on stack. This could throw exception, right?

Comment: Oh, looks like another misunderstanding discovered... Thank you!

Comment: @k2_8191: Indeed, creating an object (`Hoge hoge;`) could throw an expression. I've edited the code to match your intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delegate the `// rest of work` to a helper function, and pass a `Hoge&` to that function:

```
void RestOfWork(Hoge& hoge)
{
  // rest of work here
}

void g() {
  // work unrelated to Hoge object here

  try {
    Hoge hoge;
    RestOfWork(hoge);
    // rest of work here
  } catch(HogeException& ex) {
    // handle exception
  }
}
```

Incidentally, `Hoge hoge();` doesn't do what you think it does.  You probably think that you are declaring an object named `hoge` of type `Hoge`, and initializing it by calling the default constructor.  What you're actually doing is declaring a function named `hoge` which takes no parameters and returns a `Hoge` by-value.  I've fixed this in my code above.

**Edit** Indeed, as suggested by @LightnessRacesInOrbit, the construction of the `Hoge` object can take place in the deferral function as well, such as with:

```
  void RestOfWork()
  {
       Hoge hoge;
      // rest of work here
  }

  void g() {
    // work unrelated to Hoge object here

    try {
      RestOfWork();
    } catch(HogeException& ex) {
      // handle exception
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer. Except, possibly, in some scenarios, you might as well just create `hoge` inside `RestOfWork` in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Isn't that essentially what was being done in the first place?  Or do you mean to leave the `try...catch` in `g()`?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Indeed. `try...catch` around a call to `SomeWork()`, leaving `Hoge` in the function. Everything in the function needs `Hoge` to have been constructed, and nothing outside of the function needs to use it. So! Like you have now.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable way to do this is to use a nullable single-item container, e.g. `boost::optional`:

```
void g() {
  // work unrelated to Hoge object here

  boost::optional<Hoge> opt_hoge;
  try {
    opt_hoge = boost::in_place<Hoge>();
  } catch(HogeException& ex) {
    // handle exception
  }
  Hoge &hoge = *opt_hoge;

  // rest of work here
}
```

If you can't use Boost, `std::unique_ptr` would work at the cost of a heap allocation:

```
void g() {
  // work unrelated to Hoge object here

  std::unique_ptr<Hoge> opt_hoge;
  try {
    opt_hoge = std::unique_ptr<Hoge>(new Hoge);
  } catch(HogeException& ex) {
    // handle exception
  }
  Hoge &hoge = *opt_hoge;

  // rest of work here
}
```